# How to check client web socket enable/disable using jquery

Tags: jquery, websocket

I want to check on client site that  client web socket enable/disable using jquery.
My application will open in browser/iPhone, iPad may be on Android, I have to identify that client web socket is enable or disable.

Answer (score 2):

You can check using the code below.

```
var support = "MozWebSocket" in window ? 'MozWebSocket' : ("WebSocket" in window ? 'WebSocket' : null);
if(support==null) {
// WebSockets aren't supported
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try haz.io

http://haz.io/

If you want to do it in a script use something like Modernizr.

http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#polyfills

you can utilize yepnope.js and load a websocket polyfil to add websockets or a suitable replacement for clients without Websockets.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this.**

```
 if ('WebSocket' in window) {
       webSocket = new WebSocket(url);
 } else if ('MozWebSocket' in window) {
       webSocket = new MozWebSocket(url);
 } else {
        Console.log('Error: WebSocket is not supported by this browser.');
                 return;
 }
```